# on Create and on Start method not called

Tags: android

Actually i have created an singleton class. Now my singleton class extends Activity, and i have write `onCreate()` and `onStart()` method on this class. But it is never called.The code i have used is shown below. If anyone knows help me to solve these out.

**Code**

```
public class cycleManager
{
private static CycleManager m_cycleManagerObj;

private CycleManager()
{           
    // Initialise Variable
    onInitialization();

    readData(this); // show error when call from here
}   

public static synchronized CycleManager getSingletonObject() 
{           
    if (m_cycleManagerObj == null)
    {
        m_cycleManagerObj = new CycleManager();
    }               
    return m_cycleManagerObj;
}

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
{           
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException(); 
}

public void writeData(Context c) 
{
    SharedPreferences preferencesWrite  = c.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = preferencesWrite.edit();
    // work to be done
}
public void readData(Context c)
{
    SharedPreferences preferencesRead = c.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", 0);
    // work to be done
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is Android manages activities in its own manner: from calling a constructor to calling all lifecycle methods. So if you declare your Activity's constructor as private then Android will not be able to manage this activity.

Why do you need singleton Activity-class? Consider [different launch modes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes)

Comment: Actually this is the class where i put all the methods that need for performing operation.So whenever in which activity  i need this this method..i simply create an instance of that class and call which ever method i want.

Comment: You shouldn't use Activity class to hold such methods. Use separate class for this as you do it now. You should consider Activity class only as a representation of individual screen.

Comment: To clarify, not necessarily an individual screen, but the UI necessary for an individual task. Otherwise, a.ch. is spot on. Singleton Activities are **bad** ideas and are setting yourself up for memory leaks. You should probably read up on the Activity Lifecycle and conventions before trying something like this.

Comment: Yeh you two are right.But suppose i have many function which can be used by other activity class based on situation then what should i do,Instead of writing it to in all the activities, i simple create a class which doesn't extends activity, and write all my useful function there and make this class singleton.So ehenever which function is required by which activity, it simple call the instance of that singleton class and acess it method.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. You may also create some `BasicActivity` which others activities would extend instead of `Activity` (but this is a case if you only need to subclass `Activity`, not `ListActivity`, etc).

Comment: Now my question is suppose i have two activity A, B and one class C which is not an activity class. Class C is singleton class and have method which is used by A and B. Suppose there are two method which write data to device and read Data from device in Class C, and for that i have used sharedPreference. Now i call witeData() function on exit of an app. But when the app start where is the best place fron where i can call readData() function. Intially i call it from onStart() of Activity A. But if i tried to read it from constructor of class C it shows error.Why is happen.

Comment: It's hard to point out the exact reason for the error not seeing the code and stacktrace, but I suppose it is an initialization problem. The right place to read data depends on what type of data you read. If it's not being updated during application run - then call it in `onCreate(..)` method, otherwise call it when data is updated.

Comment: Actually you don't get my question.I mean to say that it works fine when i call it from the onStart() of Activity A which is an activity class. But when i call it from Class C which is not an activity class and it doesn't have onStart() / onCreate() method then it shows error, although the functions is on Class C only.So why this occur.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6789/discussion-between-a-ch-and-anshuman)

Answer (score 1):

check your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:name=".ActivityName">
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not public method.They are protected method.You should override existing method.try like the following.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
    }

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that Android is supposed to be managing your activity lifecycle, not you.

onCreate and onStart (along with onPause, onDestroy and all the other android activity lifecycle functions) are called by the looper on Android's main thread.

How did you start this activity?  Was it declared in your manifest as your main activity and launcher?  Did you call startActivity and pass the class name?

The fact that you are creating a singleton instance of your activity, and that its constructor is private, suggests to me that Android would be unable to start this activity when you want it to, though some function for passing an existing activity to be managed may exist, and I've just never seen it.

If onCreate and onStart are never being called, it means Android doesn't know it is supposed to be running your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because your class is not a subclass of `Context`. Add `Context` attribute to getSingletonObject(Context context) method and pass it to CycleManager(Context context) constructor.